# jump pagination forward and backward with firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I'm using firestore, and  I want to make pagination, you know, for example:
case 1:
The user is on page 1 and then the user wants to jump to page 10.
case 2:
The user is on page 10 and then the user wants to jump to page 1.

So how can I do that?
Are there examples of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Firestore pagination API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) doesn't support paging by item index or page number.  You can only cycle through query results using document information that you previously read from another page.

If you want to implement a UI that performs indexed paging, you'll have to read the entire set of results and split them up into pages on your own.

Comment: humm, I see.
So what happens if each pages shows 10 items and I have 5.000 items and I want to go to the page 4.999. I have to get the 4.999 items and then split it just for show 10 items. Right?

Comment: If not that, you would have to reverse the sort and start from the end end of the results.